# Integrating ASP.NET Webforms, WebAPI and AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api, webforms

I'm trying to get my first ASP.NET Webforms and AngularJS app up and running, but I'm struggling...

I created a blank, new ASP.NET 4.5.1 webforms app, and included WebAPI into the mix. I created a sample page for my list of customers, and a standard, EF6-based WebAPI `CustomerController : ApiController` with all the usual CRUD methods. I tested that WebAPI using Fiddler and low and behold - I get my 8 customers back from my database.

Getting this into AngularJS however has been a bit of a unsuccessful and highly frustrating experience ....

I included `AngularJS` from NuGet and that seems to have worked - no errors shown or anything, a pile of `angular*.js` files dumped into my `Scripts` folder.

I created a basic `CustomerList.aspx` page based on a master page which includes the `<html lang="en" ng-app="TestAngular">` tag.

In order to get the data from the WebAPI service, I created my Angular module, and created a `model` inside the `$scope`, and created a service to fetch the data from the WebAPI:

Inside `app.js`:

```
var testModule = angular.module('TestAngular', [ ]);

testModule.controller('clientController', function ($scope, clientService) {
    $scope.model = [];
    clientService.getAllClients(function(results) {
        $scope.model.clients = results;
    });

    $scope.model.clientCount = $scope.model.clients.count;
});

testModule.factory('clientService', function ($http) {
    var srv = {};
    srv._baseUrl = 'http://localhost:56313';

    // Public API
    return {
        getAllClients: function(callback) {
            return $http.get(srv._baseUrl + '/api/Customer').success(callback);
        }
    };
});
```

From what limited Javascript understanding I have, this should define a `clientService` (the `testModule.factory()` call) that calls my WebAPI URL, gets the JSON back, and the callback function then stuffs those customers retrieved into the `$scope.model.clients` property, and the `$scope.model.clientCount` should also be calculated.

My ASPX page looks something like this:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="CustomerList.aspx.cs" Inherits="TestAngular.CustomerList" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master"  %>

<asp:Content runat="server" ID="content" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <h2>My customers</h2>

    <div class="panel panel-default" data-ng-controller="clientController">
        We have a total of {{ model.clientCount }} clients in our database table ...

        <div class="list-group" data-ng-repeat="client in model.clients">
            <div class="list-group-item">
                <span>{{ client.Name }}</span><br/>
                <span>{{ client.Name2 }}</span><br/>
            </div>     
        </div>
    </div>
</asp:Content>
```

So the `<div>` with the `data-ng-controller` should "connect" that DIV with the AngularJS controller, should load the customers from the WebAPI call, and contain them in the model, which would then be rendered to the ASPX page using the data binding syntax (`{{ client.Name }}` etc.)

Trouble is: the call to the WebAPI happens and the correct 8 customers are returned, however, when I debug into the Javascript code, the `clientCount` is always `undefined` and the ASPX page only shows two empty rows which probably would correspond to customers that have been retrieved - but why only 2, not 8 ??

I'm totally lost and stuck - can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong, what I'm missing here??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are definately on the right track.  At the moment, the problem is down to the `clientService` `getAllClients` method.

You should `return` the promise and then the data will chain through to the controller:

```
getAllClients: function(callback) {
    return $http.get(srv._baseUrl + '/api/Customer').success(callback);
}
```

You may also want to take a look at the count line:

```
$scope.model.clientCount = $scope.model.clients.count;
```

Before the promise is resolved (and the callback is invoked), `$scope.model.clients` will be `undefined`.  So, I'd expect this line to fail.  Also, to get the *count* of an array, you need `length`.

You should set the `clientCount` inside of the callback:

```
clientService.getAllClients(function(results) {
    $scope.model.clients = results;
    $scope.model.clientCount = $scope.model.clients.length;
});
```

**Edit:**

Typically, it is favoured to use the promise returned by `$http`.  So, the controller would slightly change to:

```
clientService.getAllClients().then(function(response) {
    $scope.model.clients = response.results;
    $scope.model.clientCount = response.results.length;
});
```

And then the service would change to:

```
getAllClients: function() {
    return $http.get(srv._baseUrl + '/api/Customer');
}
```

Angular uses promises from [$q](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q) instead of callbacks (for most apis).  They make chaining and exception handling much easier.

Also, since, in this case, you know you are handling a promise from `$http`, you can use the `success` method in the controller as well:

```
clientService.getAllClients().success(function(results) {
    $scope.model.clients = results;
    $scope.model.clientCount = results.length;
});
```

`success` unwraps the response and sends only the body through to the callback.

Comment: Thanks - tried this - still don't see anything useful on screen :-( It's still the same as before....

Comment: I just realized that you are using a callback instead of a promise mechanism.  I'll edit the answer to show what is typically done.

Comment: Sorry, I think you want `model.clients.length` instead.

Comment: @DavinTryon, I would have avoided using `.success` - it is an `$http`-only function and not per-promise-spec. Also, any `.then` inside `getAllClients` would break this usage. Also, I'd wager that the `callback` approach would have worked had there been a `$scope.$apply` in the callback function, but promises is definitely the way to go.

Comment: It seems that the first approach you showed (with the `getAllClients: function(callback) {...}` works just fine - the two others (with the `getAllClients().then(function())` and the `getAllClients().success(function())` don't show any data and don't seem to update the `clientCount` at all :-(

Comment: @marc_s I've had a second look and the promisified version should work.  Make sure that the `$http.get` call is returned.  That should do it.  Is there an error?  Does the call make it into the `then` or `success`?

Comment: @DavinTryon: I've updated my question - your second version seems to work - almost - up to a weird error which I truly don't understand...... any ideas?

Comment: @DavinTryon: ok, adding the `return` to the `getAllClients()` method on the service helped :-)) It now works just fine - both of your versions (with callback, and the second one, too) - thanks for all your help !